# Is the $\ell$-adic cohomology of a non-proper variety unramified at good primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth variety of finite type over a number field $k$. Let $\overline{X} = X \times_{k} \overline{k}$, and let $\ell$ be a prime. It's well known that if $X$ is proper, then the étale cohomology groups $H^i_{et}(\overline{X}, \mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$ are unramified at any prime $\mathfrak{p} \nmid \ell$ at which $X$ has good reduction (and in fact are isomorphic as representations of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}_\mathfrak{p} / K_\mathfrak{p})$ to the étale cohomology groups of the special fibre).

Does this statement also hold if $X$ is not assumed to be proper? (I'm interested in the case of smooth affine varieties.) What about the weaker statement that $H^i_{et}(\overline{X}, \mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$ is unramified almost everywhere?

(I don't know a reference for the proof of the "well known" statement -- I couldn't find it in Milne's books or in SGA 4.5.)

Comment: This is just in reference to your parenthetical comment. For proper smooth maps, the unramifiedness is a consequence of the general fact that local constancy for $\ell$-adic sheaves is stable under push-forward by proper smooth maps. This is Thm 20.2 in Milne's online notes.

Comment: @Keerthi: Can you elaborate a little on why unramifiedness follows from this pushforward result?

Comment: David--Replace $k$ with its completion at a good prime, and suppose that $\pi:\mathfrak{X}\to Spec~\mathcal{O}_k$ is a smooth proper model for $X$ over $\mathcal{O}_k$. Then $R^i\pi_*\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ is a locally constant sheaf over $Spec~\mathcal{O}_k$ whose stalk over the geometric generic point is $H^i_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$. This means that the action of $\Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ on the cohomology group factors through $\pi_1$ of $Spec~\mathcal{O}_k$, which is the same as the absolute Galois group of the residue field.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to use the properness in a completely essential way, though.

Comment: I think the weaker statement is true, but for the main question it depends what you mean by "good reduction".  Could you specify?

Comment: Yes, you really need to say what you mean by good reduction. If you mean "the generic fiber of a smooth morphism", then every smooth variety has this property (just take a model over the good primes), so anything with ramified cohomology is a counterexample. If you mean the complement of a proper flat closed subscheme in a smooth proper scheme, then deleting a ramified closed point from the projective line should give a counterexample. If you mean the complement of a smooth proper closed subscheme in a smooth proper scheme, then it's probably true.

Comment: See the argument in Section 4 of Deligne's "Formes modulaires et representations l-adiques" for an example where one can make such conclusions for a non-proper variety (i.e. the bottom of p.13 of http://math.bu.edu/people/potthars/writings/deligne-l-adic.pdf). It uses a version of Abhyankar's lemma discussed in SGA 1 Expose XIII.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the weaker statement should be true.  Here's a sketch of an argument: by compactification theorems and resolution of singularities, there is a smooth proper
scheme $Y$ over $k$ containing $X$ as an open subscheme, such that $Y \setminus X$ is a
divisor $D$ with simple normal crossings.  Let $D_1, \dots, D_r$ be the irreducible components of $D$.  Then any $p$-fold intersection of the $D_i$'s is smooth and proper
over $k$.

There should be a spectral sequence, in terms of the etale cohomology of $\overline{Y}$ and that of the intersections of the $D_i$'s, that abuts to the etale cohomology of $\overline{X}$.  Thus the etale cohomology of $\overline{X}$ should be unramified at any prime of good reduction for $\overline{Y}$ and all of the intersections of the $D_i$'s.  I imagine you could also use this to show that at such primes the cohomology of $\overline{X}$
was isomorphic to the cohomology of the reduction.

David

Comment: So what's the definition of 'good reduction' used in this answer?

Comment: The answer only considers "good reduction" for $Y$ and the intersections of the $D_i$'s which are all proper, so we know what good reduction means there, don't we?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that this was an answer to the weaker question. FYI it's also in SGA 4.5. It follows from constructibility of higher direct images.